# Model Data in Partial View Not Rendering in Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create a pop-up dialog box which details the data on my Model. This dialog is created as Partial View. The problem is everything works fine except for the Model. There is data on my model but it is not appearing on HTML in the dialog.

Here is my code, on my Main View, I add the last line to create a partial view

```
<button id="btnList" class="btn btn-blue" type="button" 
title="List Details">List Details</button>

<div id="divList">
    @Html.Partial("_List", Model)
</div>
```

And on my controller to call the Partial View:

```
public PartialViewResult fncList(entityList objModel)
{
    objModel.strList= "Test Data";
    return PartialView("_List", objModel);
}
```

I am calling this fncList via JQuery function:

```
  function fncListData() {

        $('#btnList').unbind();
        $('#btnList').on('click', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var objData = $('form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("fncList", Model)',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'application/JSON',
                data: objData,
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                complete: function (request, status) {
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divList').dialog('open');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                }
            });                   
            });
    }
```

I also declare my partial View as dialog in my Main View:

```
 $("#divList").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            maxWidth: 500,
            maxHeight: 300,
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            title: "List of Data"
        });
```

On my partial view - this is where the problem occurs.

```
@model entityList
<div><span>@Model.strList</span></div>
```

Every-time I call any Model data example `@Model.strList`, the dialog is just blank although there is data on it and I even verified it while debugging in View. I want to populate my dialog with details of my Model data but its not appearing in HTML.
I also tried:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.strList)
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: Where and how are you calling your `fncList()` method (using `@Html.Partial()` does not call a controller method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited my post. I am calling it via JS function inside my Main view via function fncListData().

Comment: @WillyDavidJr, You are onlying bind the click handler, not actually `clicking` the button

Comment: @Satpal Yes. There is already a data upon binding it, since the controller function will be called then it will return to partial view with the data on it, which on this case is objModel.strList= "Test Data".

Comment: You script is not really making sense. Why do you have a `.click()` handler inside the function. Where are you calling that `fncListData()` function from. And what is the element with `id="btnList"`?

Comment: Also `datatype: 'application/JSON',` would throw an exception (you return html, not json)

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke, I added a #btnList button on my code. When someone click that button, fncListData() will fire which will call the public PartialViewResult fncList method on my controller view.

Comment: Start by removing `$('#btnList').unbind();` and `$('#btnList').on('click', function(e) {` - the function should just include the ajax code. And in the success callback, you first need to update the html with the results you return, then open the dialog